# IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1 while indexing with a list

Tags: python, pytorch

So I am solving a machine learning problem and in one of my functions I try to index a `torch.tensor` with a list of tensors and sometimes indexing works and sometimes it does not. I am aware of situations when this error usually occurs, that is, when one tries to index 1D array with 2 or more indices, but it should not occur when I index with a list of indexes (from my understanding).

So below I present exact reproducible situation that happened to me. I have two lists of tensors produced by the same fragment of code.

```
>>> a
[tensor(7, device='cuda:0'), tensor(3, device='cuda:0'), tensor(5, device='cuda:0'), tensor(0, device='cuda:0'), tensor(4, device='cuda:0'), tensor(24, device='cuda:0'), tensor(27, device='cuda:0'), tensor(2, device='cuda:0'), tensor(6, device='cuda:0'), tensor(9, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18, device='cuda:0'), tensor(31, device='cuda:0'), tensor(1, device='cuda:0'), tensor(8, device='cuda:0')]
>>> b
[tensor(20319, device='cuda:0'), tensor(19303, device='cuda:0'), tensor(20181, device='cuda:0'), tensor(17466, device='cuda:0'), tensor(4941, device='cuda:0'), tensor(21132, device='cuda:0'), tensor(17381, device='cuda:0'), tensor(17332, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18432, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18205, device='cuda:0'), tensor(19689, device='cuda:0'), tensor(20743, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18466, device='cuda:0'), tensor(16804, device='cuda:0'), tensor(17521, device='cuda:0'), tensor(21147, device='cuda:0'), tensor(16152, device='cuda:0'), tensor(14863, device='cuda:0'), tensor(15458, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18847, device='cuda:0'), tensor(21549, device='cuda:0'), tensor(21203, device='cuda:0'), tensor(17209, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18552, device='cuda:0'), tensor(16517, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18763, device='cuda:0'), tensor(19538, device='cuda:0'), tensor(12202, device='cuda:0'), tensor(19727, device='cuda:0'), tensor(21218, device='cuda:0'), tensor(8635, device='cuda:0'), tensor(15368, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18322, device='cuda:0'), tensor(17593, device='cuda:0'), tensor(17529, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18036, device='cuda:0'), tensor(12566, device='cuda:0'), tensor(18911, device='cuda:0'), tensor(7387, device='cuda:0'), tensor(16160, device='cuda:0'), tensor(20432, device='cuda:0'), tensor(16536, device='cuda:0'), tensor(14990, device='cuda:0')]
>>> c = torch.ones(100000)
>>> c[a]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
>>> c[b]
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

In the end I did solve it by casting list to `torch.tensor`, but it bugs me why is this happening. Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: I found out that it has something to do with the length. Setting `e = [torch.tensor(i) for i in range(31)]` and `f = [torch.tensor(i) for i in range(32)]`, `c[e]` does not work, while `c[f]` does. Still do not know why, sorry

Comment: As Jasper said, it is something with the list length 32. E.g., `c[b[:31]]` will not work, but `c[b[:32]]` will work. Likely there is some `if not isinstance(index, Tensor) and len(index) > 32` somewhere  (in the C level) for reasons we cannot comprehend at the moment.

Comment: As reference one Issue about this on GitHub: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/68595

Answer (score 0):

I first reproduce the bug and the suggestions of Jasper and Daraan:

```
c = torch.arange(0,1000,1)
b = [torch.tensor(i) for i in range(1000)]
print("List lengths for which there is an index error: ", end=" ")
for i in range(10000):
    try:
        c[b[:i]]
    except IndexError:
        print(f"{i}", end=", ")
```

The output is:

```
List lengths for which there is an index error: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31
```

This proves that the only list lengths that give an index error are between 2 and 31 included (I am using torch version 2.0.1+cu117).

We observe the same behavior if we reshape the one-dimensional tensor c into a matrix of shape (1000,1):

```
c = torch.arange(0,1000,1).reshape(1000,1)
```

Interestingly, in both cases, encapsulating the list of tensors as the unique element of a list (using `c[[b]]` instead of `c[b]`) doesn't give the error. This means that the following code doesn't return any error for any tested index length (the only change with respect to the code above is the line `c[[b[:i]]]`):

```
c = torch.arange(0,1000,1)
b = [torch.tensor(i) for i in range(1000)]
print("List lengths for which there is an index error: ", end=" ")
for i in range(10000):
    try:
        c[[b[:i]]]
    except IndexError:
        print(f"{i}", end=", ")
```